# Setting custom position of CENTER.CROP images in gallery. Cutting bottom part of image instead of top one

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-gallery

I have a problem with centering images in gallery. I want them to fill maximum space available in gallery but don't want them to be cutted on top of the screen. I'd like to see theirs top parts rather than bottom ones.

**My question is how can I set the position so that I can see the 'top part' of an image in gallery?**

```
images.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)
```

sets the image to fill all the available space maintaining its ratio. The problem is my images are more higher than widther and in result the top part of them isn't visible.

I have a custom gallery: CustomGallery which layout is:

```
android:id="@+id/photos_gallery"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fadingEdge="none"
android:spacing="0dp"
```

The gallery uses adapter: GalleryAdapter which extends BaseAdapter. Its getView method is following:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(mcontext);
    image.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
        android.widget.Gallery.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        android.widget.Gallery.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));      
    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);        

    image.setImageBitmap(getImgSource(position));   

    return image;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
images.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START)
```

From the documentation:

> Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but
>   will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis
>   (X or Y) will fit exactly. START aligns the result to the left and top
>   edges of dst.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#START

Comment: isn't this the reference link? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: @Spoonface.  I just linked to the fitStart tag.